# How to prevent Yii from opening the database automatically

Tags: yii

I am using Yii 1.1.17 for my portal. I use the same application to connect into different databases depending on domain name.
I write the fake params in **`main.php`**

```
'db'=>array(
   'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db',           
   'emulatePrepare' => TRUE,
   'active' => FALSE,
   'username' => 'dbUser',
   'password' => 'dbP@ssW0rd',
   'charset' => 'utf8'
),
```

Then change them in **`Controller.php`** like this:

```
// get database params from url
        $url = Yii::app()->request->serverName;
        $db_param = explode(".",$url);
        $db = Yii::app()->params['db'][$db_param[0]];
        Yii::app()->db->setActive(false);
        Yii::app()->db->connectionString = mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=$db";
        Yii::app()->db->username = $db;
        Yii::app()->db->setActive(true);
```

`username` is the same as `dbname`, and `password` is the same for all databases.
When I open the portal it gives me

```
 CDbException
 CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.
```

But when I write the real values of live database in `connectionString` and `username` inside **`main.php`** it opens then changes this values and connects into correct database.

My question is:
How to prevent Yii to connect automatically before running code in **`Controller.php`**. I set `'active' => FALSE`, but it does not help.

Comment: Please try to set `'autoConnect' => FALSE,`, may be it helps, more info https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#autoConnect-detail

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yii won't initialize `db` component and open DB connection until you use it. So if your connection is opened, maybe you're actually using this component somewhere before controller is run (other components may use it)?

But most likely you're initializing it yourself in your controller - accessing `Yii::app()->db` will initialize `db` component and open DB connection. You should use [`setComponent()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModule#setComponent-detail) to override it:

```
Yii::app()->setComponent('db', [
    'class' => 'CDbConnection',
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'active' => false,
    'username' => 'dbUser',
    'password' => 'dbP@ssW0rd',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
]);
```

Or

```
Yii::app()->setComponent('db', Yii::createComponent([
    'class' => 'CDbConnection',
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'active' => false,
    'username' => 'dbUser',
    'password' => 'dbP@ssW0rd',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
]));
```

Comment: Maybe when I close it in Controller.php, it opens db first.

Yii::app()->db->setActive(false);

But the way, that recommended Vitalijs G. works